# How can I add or subtract 3 items in a list based on a list of 2 operators in Python?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, operators

Say I had a list `number_list = [3,4,9]`

And I wanted to operate on the numbers in the list based on a list such as `operators = ['+', '-']`

This program would take these lists and operate on the numbers using the list. Using the example lists, the following would be equated:

```
3 + 4 - 9
```

And the function would return the result of this equation.

Whilst I know the order for plus and minus operations does not matter, I plan on using this with multiplication and division as well, where order does matter.

Thank you to anyone who can provide some insight as to how I would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy solution that **does not care about security** (read up on the "bad things" eval can do)

```
number_list = [3, 4, 9, 5]
operators = ["+", "-", '*']

# create a new list that can hold the above lists
new = [None] * (len(number_list) + len(operators))

# assign the first list using slice assignment
new[::2] = number_list
# assign the second list using slice assignment
new[1::2] = operators
# make all the elements to a string and eval
res = eval(''.join(map(str, new)))
print(res)
```

Output

`-38`

Assumption

`operators` must have valid operators and must be exactly one less than the size of `number_list`. Again, `eval` is not the way to go if you are doing this in actual production code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't really understand how and why my question got down voted, I see this as a pretty obscure question but anyways. This is for a school assignment so I'm sure I can talk about the security vulnerability in my evaluation

Comment: @joelwright-dev There's a close vote for needing more focus. My guess is that whoever downvoted thought that you didn't show a good faith attempt to solve the problem (perhaps you did, but we only know as much information as you write in the original question). Too often, people dump homework prompts in the question body and then ask SO users to solve it -- in essence, people try to use SO like Chegg, and SO users tend to frown upon that.

Comment: In this case, I think what you've written is probably fine, since you've clearly given some thought to the problem. Don't worry too much about it.